# Unsure how to infer function parameter types

Tags: javascript, typescript

With the following code, how would I replace the `any`s if it is even possible. I would like to remove the warning from TS "*Unexpected any. Specify a different type*"

```js
interface Props {
    isPrime: boolean;
}
interface Other {
    isEdit: boolean;
}
type TFunc = (a: any, b: any) => any;
const myFunc = (c: TFunc) => (a: any) => (b: any) => c(a, b);

const funcA = myFunc((props: Props, other: Other) => {
    // ..somecode
}
// Code to call the func A result ect.
```

Comment: Hint: `myFunc` should be named `curry`, that's the standard name for this functionality. You will find lots of generic typings for it when search for that term.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. WIll keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) type

```
interface Props {
  isPrime: boolean;
}
interface Other {
  isEdit: boolean;
}
type TFunc<T, U> = (a: T, b: U) => any;
const myFunc = <T, U>(c: TFunc<T, U>) => (a: T) => (b: U) => c(a, b);

const funcA = myFunc<Props, Other>((props: Props, other: Other) => {
  // ..somecode
});
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you

Comment: Still one `any` left that should be made a type parameter…